# How to update KDE menu in Linux Mint without logging out?

Tags: linux-mint, menu

I don't know why, but when I install any application in my several Linux Mint 17.2 KDE systems, I need to log out and log in again to have an icon in the menu.

Is there a way to update the menu without logging out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on openSUSE KDE, the newly installed apps have their icons available in a **Recently Installed** sub-menu during the current session.

They appear in their rightful place after restarting the KDE session (the special sub-menu disappears).